# Asyncio and Multiprocessing with python

Tags: python

I try executing code example from 
[snakepit-game game_loop_process.py](https://github.com/7WebPages/snakepit-game/blob/master/simple/game_loop_process.py)

but I get this exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1043, in create_server
    sock.bind(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10048] 一次只能用一個通訊端位址 (通訊協定/網路位址/連接埠)。
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\testarea\game_loop_process.py", line 99, in <module>
    web.run_app(app,host='127.0.0.1',port=1234)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web.py", line 457, in run_app
    asyncio.gather(*server_creations, loop=loop)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1047, in create_server
    % (sa, err.strerror.lower()))
OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address ('127.0.0.1', 1234): 一次只能用一個通訊端位址 (通訊協定/網路位址/連接埠)。
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] 存取被拒。
```

what am I doing wrong ??
environment : win10
python version :Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)|

Answer (score 1):

```
OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address ('127.0.0.1', 1234): 一次只能用一個通訊端位址 (通訊協定/網路位址/連接埠)。
```

It seems this says you cannot bind the port for the server to listen to it. The error message (in chinese) comes from your system, and says: "[Only one communication address (protocol / network address / port) can be used at a time.](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E4%B8%80%E6%AC%A1%E5%8F%AA%E8%83%BD%E7%94%A8%E4%B8%80%E5%80%8B%E9%80%9A%E8%A8%8A%E7%AB%AF%E4%BD%8D%E5%9D%80%20(%E9%80%9A%E8%A8%8A%E5%8D%94%E5%AE%9A%2F%E7%B6%B2%E8%B7%AF%E4%BD%8D%E5%9D%80%2F%E9%80%A3%E6%8E%A5%E5%9F%A0)%E3%80%82)"

Apparently there is another program binding a server to this port, and it is most likely another instance of your program. Make sure to terminate any other instances of it, or choose another port.